# Why this script is only working in preview mode - Kentico

Tags: kentico

Why below script is only working in preview mode of Kentico CMS

```
{% Documents["/Page-Resource/Portfolio/Product-Marketo"].GetValue("Description") #%}
```

Comment: Are the documents you are getting values from published?  Live mode will show data only from published documents, but Preview mode will show data from all documents (published, or unpublished).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually had a issue with the macro permissions for document collections. In such case, disable the check by adding the following key to web.config file:

```
<add key="CMSCheckPermissionsForDocumentCollection" value="false"/>
```

Comment: The solution is correct. There was change in default behavior in the hotfix 8.1.11. More info can be found here http://devnet.kentico.com/articles/page-macro-expressions-security

Answer (score 0):

Another option:

For the document you reference in your macro, go to **Properties > Security**, add "Public Anonymous User (public)" to the "Users and Roles" box, and check "Read" for their "Access rights". Click OK.